# reject_if option is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here's the (simplified) code:

```
class Biosimilar::AdverseEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessibile :adverse_event_med_conds_attributes

  has_many :adverse_event_med_conds, 
      :class_name => 'Biosimilar::AdverseEventMedCond', 
      :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :med_conds, 
      :class_name => 'Biosimilar::MedCond', 
      :through => :adverse_event_med_conds

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :adverse_event_med_conds,
      :allow_destroy => true,
      :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes.any? {|k,v| v.blank?} }
end
```

When the form is submitted, the record is created on "adverse_event_med_conds" table even if the user leaves the "med_cond_id" field EMPTY. The reject_if doesn't work!

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly check for that attribute? E.g. ``:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['med_cond_id'].blank? }``

Answer (score 0):

Ok, forget it. The above code is correct! The problem was in the controller, I accidentally left in the "show" method the following lines:

```
if @adverse_event.adverse_event_med_conds.size == 0
  @adverse_event.adverse_event_med_conds.build
end
```

...and the "build" call was the one that caused record creation.